# How to serve sitemap.xml in react

Tags: reactjs

I have my sitemap.xml, and I'm trying to serve it at .com/sitemap.xml

So I have that line in my App.jsx

```
import Sitemap from "./components/Sitemap";
...
<Route path="/sitemap.xml" element={<Sitemap />} />
```

But I do not manage to write properly my Sitemap.jsx:

```
function fetch_sitemap() {
    const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

    fetch('link')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            parseString(response, function (err, result) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
        })
}

const Sitemap = () => {
  return fetch_sitemap();
};

export default Sitemap;
```

Any idea I could do please? I am pretty new with react.